# How to idiomatically copy a slice?

Tags: rust, slice

In Go, copying slices is standard-fare and looks like this:

```golang
# It will figure out the details to match slice sizes
dst = copy(dst[n:], src[:m])
```

In Rust, I couldn't find a similar method as replacement. Something I came up with looks like this:

```
fn copy_slice(dst: &mut [u8], src: &[u8]) -> usize {
    let mut c = 0;
    for (&mut d, &s) in dst.iter_mut().zip(src.iter()) {
        d = s;
        c += 1;
    }
    c
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this compile-error that I am unable to solve:

```
error[E0384]: re-assignment of immutable variable `d`
 --> src/main.rs:4:9
  |
3 |     for (&mut d, &s) in dst.iter_mut().zip(src.iter()) {
  |               - first assignment to `d`
4 |         d = s;
  |         ^^^^^ re-assignment of immutable variable
```

How can I set `d`? Is there a better way to copy a slice?

Comment: Could you expand a bit on why you want to copy data in slices around? I'd usually expect to either just take a reference to the original *or* to be copying the data to something that owns the copy.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Yes, use the method [`clone_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.clone_from_slice), it is generic over any element type that implements `Clone`.

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = vec![0; 8];
    let y = [1, 2, 3];
    x[..3].clone_from_slice(&y);
    println!("{:?}", x);
    // Output:
    // [1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

The destination `x` is either a `&mut [T]` slice, or anything that derefs to that, like a mutable `Vec<T>` vector. You need to slice the destination and source so that their lengths match.

---

As of Rust 1.9, you can also use [`copy_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice). This works the same way but uses the `Copy` trait instead of `Clone`, and is a direct wrapper of `memcpy`. The compiler can optimize `clone_from_slice` to be equivalent to `copy_from_slice` when applicable, but it can still be useful.

Comment: Thank you ! This was what I was initially looking for, but couldn't find as I was searching for anything related to `copy`. In rust-speak, clone might be the appropriate term though ... I am still getting used to it all.

Answer (score 6):

This code works, even though I am not sure if it the best way to do it.

```
fn copy_slice(dst: &mut [u8], src: &[u8]) -> usize {
    let mut c = 0;
    for (d, s) in dst.iter_mut().zip(src.iter()) {
        *d = *s;
        c += 1;
    }
    c 
}
```

Apparently not specifying access permissions explicitly did the trick. However, I am still confused about this and my mental model doesn't yet cover what's truly going on there.
My solutions are mostly trial and error when it comes to these things, and I'd rather like to truly understand instead.

Comment: Your approach is correct. Your initial version didn't work because dereference patterns (like `&mut d`) creates a new variable (`d` in this case) and assigns it to a dereference of the pointer. It does not provide an ability to modify the original value, it just copies the original value; if you used it with non-`Copy` type, your program won't even compile.

Comment: BTW, you can also keep `&s` in place and write `*d = s` afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

Another variant would be

```
fn copy_slice(dst: &mut [u8], src: &[u8]) -> usize {
    dst.iter_mut().zip(src).map(|(x, y)| *x = *y).count()
}
```

Note that you have to use `count` in this case, since `len` would use the `ExactSizeIterator` shortcut and thus never call `next`, resulting in a no-op.

Comment: This is not idiomatic Rust. Iterators should generally not have side-effects, and the usage of `map` here doubly non-idomatic. If that's what you want, a `for` loop is the correct choice.

Comment: I admit this is kind of a hack, but the `for` loop requires manual tracking of the number of iterations. Instead of `map` one could probably use `inspect` to make it clearer that the „result“ will get discarded.

Comment: @Shepmaster You may want to consider the following example that's included in the official Rust docs for `collect()`, which shows the following:
`let hello: String = chars.iter().map(|&x| x as u8).map(|x| (x + 1) as char).collect();`

Comment: @code_dredd thanks, but this isn't my answer — I'm only an editor here.

Comment: @Shepmaster No worries. I'm not defending this implementation either, or anything. I just wanted to note the detail w.r.t. the lack of side-effects for iterators and/or maps.

Comment: @code_dredd oh, I see what you are saying now (I thought you were saying to put that example in the answer). The example you cite does not have side effects — it only operates on the values provided to the closures and those values are not mutable references.

Comment: Just as an extension on Shepmaster's first comment, here's a quote from the Rust reference on the Iterator trait: `map() is conceptually similar to a for loop. However, as map() is lazy, it is best used when you're already working with other iterators. If you're doing some sort of looping for a side effect, it's considered more idiomatic to use for than map().`.