# How can I write data from a slice to the same slice?

Tags: rust, slice

I want to write the end of a slice to the top of the same slice.

```
let mut foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

foo[..2].copy_from_slice(&[4..]); // error: multiple references to same data (mut and not)

assert!(foo, [4, 5, 3, 4, 5]);
```

I've seen [How to operate on 2 mutable slices of a Rust array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36244762/how-to-operate-on-2-mutable-slices-of-a-rust-array)

I want the maximum performance possible (for example, by using `foo.as_ptr()`).

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to exist a function similar to `collect` that fills up an `IterMut` from an iterator.

Comment: See also [How to idiomatically copy a slice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28219231/155423)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better way to do what I want:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    // scoped to restrict the lifetime of the borrows
    {
        let (left, right) = v.split_at_mut(3);
        assert!(left == [1, 2, 3]);
        assert!(right == [4, 5, 6]);
        for (l, r) in left.iter_mut().zip(right) {
            *l = *r;
        }
    }

    assert!(v == [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

To copy data from one range inside a slice to another in general (allowing overlap), we can't even use `.split_at_mut()`.

I would use `.split_at_mut()` primarily otherwise. (Is there anything that makes you think the bounds check is not going to be optimized out? Also, are you copying enough data that it's a small effect in comparison?)

Anyway, this is how you could wrap `std::ptr::copy` (overlap-allowing copy, a.k.a memmove) in a safe or an `unsafe` function.

```
use std::ptr::copy;
use std::ops::Range;

/// Copy the range `data[from]` onto the index `to` and following
///
/// **Panics** if `from` or `to` is out of bounds
pub fn move_memory<T: Copy>(data: &mut [T], from: Range<usize>, to: usize) {
    assert!(from.start <= from.end);
    assert!(from.end <= data.len());
    assert!(to <= data.len() - (from.end - from.start));
    unsafe {
        move_memory_unchecked(data, from, to);
    }
}

pub unsafe fn move_memory_unchecked<T: Copy>(data: &mut [T], from: Range<usize>, to: usize) {
    debug_assert!(from.start <= from.end);
    debug_assert!(from.end <= data.len());
    debug_assert!(to <= data.len() - (from.end - from.start));
    let ptr = data.as_mut_ptr();
    copy(ptr.offset(from.start as isize),
         ptr.offset(to as isize),
         from.end - from.start)
}

fn main() {
    let mut data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    move_memory(&mut data, 2..6, 0);
    println!("{:?}", data);
    move_memory(&mut data, 0..3, 5);
    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5ce8d68f8a1438f09cf3ee66a4f3d21b&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

Comment: Being a beginner in Rust can I ask how vector elements drop would work in this case for type T when type T implements Drop Trait?

Comment: Sure. `T: Copy` means that `T` is trivially copyable (byte-by-byte) and it also means `T` can not have a destructor. So we don't have to worry about drop here. (There is also no vector in this answer, just a mutable slice).

Comment: Ah yeah didn't notice the Copy constraint. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Rust [1.37 (2019-08-15)](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/08/15/Rust-1.37.0.html#library-changes) adds the library function [`slice::copy_within`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_within) which does exactly what you want:

```
let mut foo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

foo.copy_within(3 .. 5, 0);  // <-- THIS

assert_eq!(foo, [4, 5, 3, 4, 5]);
```

Answer (score 4):

If your types implement `Copy` **and** the subslices are not overlapping:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

    {
        let (left, right) = v.split_at_mut(3);
        // Perform further work to ensure slices are the same length, as needed
        left.copy_from_slice(right);
    }

    assert!(v == [4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6]);
}
```

Comment: If the two slices have different sizes, the function will panic and in my case I want to copy the 5 last bytes at the front of the same slice...

Comment: @Kerosene yep, that's why I put the comment *"ensure slices are the same length"*. ^_^