# What is the right way to have multiple linked lists and move data between them in Rust?

Tags: vector, reference, linked-list, rust, borrow-checker

What is the right way to have multiple `std::collections::LinkedList`s where the number of those lists is unknown at compile time?

I'm filling them with data as well as merging them (e.g. using `append()`).
I thought it would be good to have a vector that contains those lists, or contains references to those lists.

I have tried the following:

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn listtest() {
    let mut v: Vec<LinkedList<i32>> = Vec::new();
    v.push(LinkedList::new()); // first list
    v.push(LinkedList::new()); // second list
    v[0].push_back(1); // fill with data
    v[1].push_back(3); // fill with data
    v[0].append(&mut v[1]); // merge lists
}

fn main() {
    listtest();
}
```

This fails to compile because I have two mutable references of `v` when using `append()`. I also tried using `Vec<&mut LinkedList<i32>>`, but did not succeed.

What would be the right approach to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no **right** approach. One possibility is to use [`split_at_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at_mut). This creates two separate slices, each of which can be mutated separately from the other:

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![LinkedList::new(), LinkedList::new()];
    v[0].push_back(1);
    v[1].push_back(3);

    {
        let (head, tail) = v.split_at_mut(1);
        head[0].append(&mut tail[0]);
    }

    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

See:

- [How to get mutable references to two array elements at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30073684/155423)
- [How can I write data from a slice to the same slice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39604042/155423)
- [How to operate on 2 mutable slices of a Rust array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36244762/155423)
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

Most collections have an [`iter_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/linked_list/struct.LinkedList.html#method.iter_mut) method that returns an iterator that yields mutable references to each item in the collection. And these references can all be used at the same time! (But the references must come from the same iterator; you can't use references coming from separate calls to `iter_mut` concurrently.)

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn listtest() {
    let mut v: Vec<LinkedList<i32>> = Vec::new();
    v.push(LinkedList::new()); // first list
    v.push(LinkedList::new()); // second list
    v[0].push_back(1); // fill with data
    v[1].push_back(3); // fill with data
    let mut vi = v.iter_mut();
    let first = vi.next().unwrap();
    let second = vi.next().unwrap();
    first.append(second); // merge lists
}

fn main() {
    listtest();
}
```

Also remember that iterators have the [`nth`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.nth) method for doing the equivalent of [`next`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.next) in a loop.